# Let $A$ be nonnegative, $A$ has a linearly independent pair of nonnegative eigenvectors. Why $A$ must be reducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in  M_n$ be nonnegative.

Suppose $A$ has a
linearly independent pair of nonnegative eigenvectors.

Why $A$ must be reducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the $2$ linearly independent non - negative eigenvectors $y_1, y_2$, associated to the eigenvalues $\mu_1, \mu_2$ respectively and we  assume that matrix $A$ is irreducible.

Then, by [Perron - Frobenius theorem for irreducible, non - negative matrices,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem)  the Perron - Frobenius left eigenvector $x^T$ is the unique **positive** eigenvector (up to  a scalar) associated to the Perron - Frobenius eigenvalue $\lambda$.

So, we have that $x^T A = \lambda x^T, A y_1 = \mu_1 y$ and $A y_2 = \mu_2 y_2$. Also:
$$\lambda x^T y_1 = x^T A y_1  = x^T \mu_1 y_1= \mu_1 x^T y_1 \implies \mu_1 = \lambda,\text{ since } x^T  y_1 \gt  0.
$$
Accordingly, we can prove that $\mu_2 = \lambda$.

Now, since the eigenspace $V(\mu_1) = V(\mu_2)$ (actually it is the eigenspace $V(\lambda)$)  is one-dimensional, we have that $y_1$ is a multiple of $y_2$, which is absurd, because $y_1, y_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: - What is the Perron - Frobenius theorem for irreducible, non - negative matrices?

Comment: Just try to search " perron frobenius theorem " on wikipedia.

Comment: - I searched, but i don't understund  a part of it .Please Just give a simple explanation of the theorem for irreducible.

Comment: @H.S If any part of the Perron - Frobenius theorem is unclear to you, feel free to ask a new question about which exact part you don't understand. The reason I'm saying so is that it would be impossible to develop the theorem under this answer.

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~web6720/Perron-Frobenius_Hannah%20Cairns.pdf) helpful, but probably there will be other sources, as well, to find some proofs.